# Why is this `grep -v` not functioning as expected?

Tags: command-line, grep, tty

I have a strange issue related to `grep -v` queries. Allow me to explain:

To display connections I use `who`:

```
$ who
harry    pts/0        2016-12-08 20:41 (192.168.0.1)
james    pts/1        2016-12-08 19:28 (192.168.0.1)
timothy  pts/2        2016-12-08 02:44 (192.168.0.1)
```

The current `tty` of my terminal is `pts/0`

```
$ tty
/dev/pts/0
$ tty | cut -f3-4 -d'/'
pts/0
```

I attempt to exclude my own connection using `grep -v $(tty | cut -f3-4 -d'/')`. The expected output of this command should be `who`, without my connection. However, the output is most unexpected:

```
$ who | grep -v $(tty | cut -f3-4 -d'/')
grep: a: No such file or directory
grep: tty: No such file or directory
```

I enclose the `$(...)` in quotes and that seems to fix the "No such file or directory" issue. However, my connection is still printed even though my tty (`pts/0`) should've been excluded:

```
$ who | grep -v "$(tty | cut -f3-4 -d'/')"
harry    pts/0        2016-12-08 20:41 (192.168.0.1)
james    pts/1        2016-12-08 19:28 (192.168.0.1)
timothy  pts/2        2016-12-08 02:44 (192.168.0.1)
```

As of this point, I have absolutely no idea why the `grep` query is malfunctioning.

Comment: How about using `set -x` first... Then run your command and see what are you actually trying to `grep`...

Comment: @don_crissti ah, I see; it's telling me I'm actually `grep`ing "not a tty". How would you suggest I get around this?

Comment: use a variable: http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x721.html

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[Zachary has explained the source of the problem.](/a/328965)

While you can work around it with

```
tty=$(tty)
tty_without_dev=${tty#/dev/}
who | grep -v "$tty_without_dev"
```

That would be wrong as for instance if that tty is `pts/1`, you would end up excluding all the lines containing `pts/10`. Some `grep` implementations have a `-w` option to do a word search

```
who | grep -vw pts/1
```

would not match on `pts/10` because the `pts/1` in there is not followed by a non-word character.

Or you could use `awk` to filter on the exact value of the second field like:

```
who | awk -v "tty=$tty_without_dev" '$2 != tty'
```

If you want to do it in one command:

```
{ who | awk -v "tty=$(tty<&3)" '$2 != substr(tty,6)'; } 3<&0
```

The original stdin being  duplicated onto file descriptor 3 and restored for the `tty` command.

Comment: +1 for figuring out how to do it in one command and pointing out that mistake.

Comment: One more one liner: `tty | cut -f3-4 -d'/' | xargs -I % sh -c  "who | grep -v %"`

Answer (score 20):

From the tty info page.

> 'tty' prints the file name of the terminal connected to its standard
>   input.  It prints `not a tty' if standard input is not a terminal.

The problem is that in your example tty's stdin is a pipe, not your terminal.

You can see from this example.

```
$ tty
/dev/pts/29
$ echo | tty 
not a tty
```

To work around that you could do something like this.

```
who | grep -wv "$(ps ax | awk "\$1 == $$ {print \$2}" )"
```

There is a faster/more efficient way however it requires two commands.

```
t=$(tty)
who|grep -wv "${t:5}"
```

Comment: @Christopher are you the only one logged into your computer?

Comment: @Christopher, weird. So the `who | grep -v "$(ps ax | grep "^$$" | awk '{ print $2 }')"` produces the expected output on my box and `t=$(tty) who|grep -v "${t:5}"` produces nothing.

Comment: What shell/version are you using? `GNU bash, version 4.1.2`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49782/discussion-between-zachary-brady-and-christopher).

Comment: `ps ax | grep "^ *$$"` could false-match e.g. your shell is 123 and 1234 exists; `ps ax -otty= $$` is more robust and only one process. But I prefer your `${t:5}` or Stephane's `${t#/dev/}` (or `substr(t,6)`)

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 updated my answer to fix that false match

Comment: Please don't add disclaimers. While the intent is laudable, they don't really help the answer. If someone points out a flaw in your answer, just edit your answer to incorporate the correction.